# Restore deleted instance from persistent disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to slowly migrate my site to GCE so I don't want to pay for server time when I'm not working on the site as no one will be using it.

I tried just deleting the instance I was using and creating a new one with the same configuration, static IP, and using the same persistent disk. When it booted all the files seemed to be there, but the website I setup didn't work anymore. I just got the default Apache page.

How can I stop an instance when I'm not using it and restore it to exactly how it was?

Comment: As long as you're talking about a root persistent disk that you're booting from, all of the files should be exactly as they were when the instance was deleted. Perhaps some process needs to be manually started?

Answer (score 1):

I found if I first shut down the machine before deleting it, it restores correctly and everything works.

Comment: In that case it seems likely you were just experiencing data loss when you killed the machine.  I bet if you run `sync` before you kill it everything would work as you hoped (but I would still recommend shutting down properly if you want to retain the disk).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Make a snapshot of root persistent disk before deleting the instance. 
To restart the the instance use "new persistent disk from snapshot" as "Boot source" in the console.

Comment: If you're already booted from a root persistent disk, you don't need to make a new snapshot to boot from it after deleting the instance. You can just choose the same persistent disk when creating the new instance. (Boot Source = "Existing persistent disk")

Comment: The question was about "restore it to exactly how it was" not to start it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to shutdown/start a machine, without altering configuration or data.